# How to perform several calculations in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, function, sum

Given this data, I want to sum (tbl_basket subt), multiply by discount, add shipping charge.

```
# tbl_basket  order_id  qty    price     subt
                     1    1    10.00    10.00
                     1    4     5.00    20.00
                     1    3    12.00    36.00

# tbl_coupon        id          name discount
                     1     "10% off"    10.00

# tbl_shipping      id                   cost
                     1                   4.99

# tbl_order  coupon_id   shipping_id    total  
                     1             1        ?  # I want to update total
```

I want to query the basket:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_basket WHERE order_id = $order_id
```

Sum the items, i think like this?

```
SELECT SUM(subt) FROM tbl_basket WHERE order_id = $order_id
```

Query the discount

```
SELECT discount FROM tbl_coupon AS coupon
          INNER JOIN tbl_order AS order
               WHERE coupon.id = order.coupon_id
```

Q) How do I merge this query into the other one in MySQL?

Q) How do set the value after the discount (new total = total*(100-discount)/100)

I felt it would make the system more robust by summing totals from the database directly, thats why I wanted to do it this way.

Q) Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In general, for larger websites, the less load on the database server the better.  You can just do it all in php.

Comment: Thanks, I might end up doing that. Although, for educational purposes, I'd still like to know a few methods of doing this in MySQL. @evan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with evan - doing the calculations in PHP is much better.  If nothing else, you can better see what you're doing!

But if you really want to see what it looks like in SQL, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT ((select total price query)*(select discount query) + (select shipping query))
```

Sure, with subqueries you might get everything into a single query statement.  The more you add, though, the harder it is to debug.  In PHP it's much easier to assemble the pieces.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the way to do it is to apply maths operators to the sub-SELECT statements to get the total then. @geoB

Answer (score 1):

I am also inclined to agree with the others who have said you should stick to doing this in PHP although there is little difference in overhead.  You could use the following query to calculate the final total with minimal overhead as long as all the necessary indices are in place.

```
SELECT (SUM(b.subt) * ((100 - MIN(c.discount)) / 100)) + MIN(s.cost) AS final_total
FROM tbl_order o
INNER JOIN tbl_basket b
    ON o.id = b.order_id
INNER JOIN tbl_shipping s
    ON s.id = o.shipping_id
INNER JOIN tbl_coupon c
    ON c.id = o.coupon_id
WHERE o.id = 1
GROUP BY o.id;
```

Comment: @nnichols - the overhead difference is that you can move the calculations to another computer altogether.  In general, you can buy front end web servers cheap.  Database servers are often a bottleneck and they're usually pricey.  Of course, this only really applies when you're talking about large scale websites for big companies.

Comment: @evan agree totally. In my case however, doing a project for a friend (small web start-up business).